# Get exchange rates from a certain date with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, currency

I would like to create an Excel function that can get the exchange rate between two given currencies at a given date. Something like: =GetFX("USD","GBP","31/12/2020")

I found the below code on a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4onnkq/exchange_rates_from_a_certain_date_automatically/) which is exactly doing that, except that it is quite outdated and no longer work with Oanda. I don't know how to use Excel VBA with external data and could not figure out what is wrong. I would very much appreciate if someone knows how to fix it.

Thanks!

```
Function GetOandaFX(fromCurr As String, toCurr As String, AsofDate As Date) As String

Dim oHttp As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim TDelements As Object
Dim TDelement As Object

' Create an XMLHTTP object
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
         
' get the URL to open
 sURL = "https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates?" _
    & "date=" & AsofDate _
    & "date_fmt=us" _
    & "&exch=" & fromCurr _
    & "&sel_list=" & toCurr _
    & "&value=1&format=HTML&redirected=1"
  
' open connection and get website html
oHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
oHttp.send
 
Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

With HTMLdoc
    If oHttp.readyState = 4 And oHttp.Status = 200 Then 'readystate checks loading, status checks the validity of URL

'    ' assign the returned text to a HTML document
    .body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText
      
    Set TDelements = .getElementsByTagName("TD")
    'Loop within Table elements
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If RateFound = True Then
            GetOandaFX = TDelement.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
        If TDelement.innerText = toCurr Then RateFound = True
    Next
    End If
End With

Set oHttp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: For historical forex rates, I'd suggest taking a look at [https://www.alphavantage.co/](https://www.alphavantage.co/) and using their API.  The API is free for occasional use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions from [VBA.CurrencyExchange](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.CurrencyExchange).

The services, that this project addresses, are:

```
  The European Central Bank
  The Danish National Bank
  The Central Bank of the Russian Federation
  Currency Converter API
  Currencylayer API
  ExchangeRate API
  Fixer
  Open Exchange Rates
  php.mk (National Bank of the Republic of North Macedonia)
  XE
```

Way too much code to post here, so study the code and the link to the [full documentation](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33199/Exchange-Rates-and-Currency-Conversion-in-VBA.html?preview=yzcXU8BAUmw%3D).

Comment: Thanks Gustav, looks like a good tool, but it seems tailored for people with advanced coding skills. They do not provide an example Excel spreadsheet for simple users like me (there is a demo file, but it seems to be for Access). Unfortunately I don't have the skills to make that work.

Comment: An Excel demo has been included in the zip for download.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gustav, the Excel demo is very helpful. I can now use a formula like =CurrencyConvertCbr("USD","EUR") to get the current exchange rate. However, I could not figure out how to add a date parameter to retrieve the rate at a specific point in time in the past. Is that possible?

Comment: Some of the services offer that option by adding yet a parameter in the URL, but I haven't checked that (visit the URL listed at top of each ExchangesRate function). The functions are mostly thought of to retrieve exchange rates on a daily base and to be stored locally should you need them later. An example is [ExchangeRate-API](https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/historical-data-requests).

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I tried to figure it out, but could not make it work. I was looking for a simple solution, this is too advanced for my coding skills. I ended up using a good old Excel table with historical data and an INDEX+MATCH function. It is clearly not as clean/automatic as I would have like, but it makes the job. Nevertheless, very much appreciate your work, thanks for sharing and I am sure it will be helpful for people with the right skills!